# Position icons with x and y coordinates on top of another image using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have an image, and I want to place an icon on top of it. The icon has x and y coordinates with respect to the big image. How can I position them on top of it using jQuery and CSS? I want to append the icon to the image because I have a lopp of many icons and I want to add them dynamically.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="image-class">
    <img id="map-view" src="/image1.png">
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#map-view {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain; 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any example  or live link or fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Since you provided very little information, i am assuming your fetching icon json array from db via AJAX each item in array like
{
 'image_url' : icon_url
  'x' : 50,
  'y' : 10
}
CSS:

```
#image-class{
 position:absolute;
}

#image-class .icon{
 position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
// list_of_icons is from db via AJAX or somthing
    for(var i=0;i<count(list_of_icons);i++)
    {
      $("<img />").attr('src',list_of_images[i].img_url).addClass('icon').css({top:list_of_images[i].y+'px',left:list_of_images[i].x+'px'}).appendTo("#image-class");
    }
```